# errors after changing from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi im attempting to change from mysql to mysqli and ive used a editor that changes it all and im getting the following error after changing all files
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/matureco/public_html/config/db_connect.php on line 7

heres the piece of coding for that

```
    $conn       = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS) or die($mysqli->error);

$row        = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli->query("select * from settings where id = '1' "));
$site_name  = trim(stripslashes($row['site_name']));
$email      = trim($row['email']);
$keyword    = trim(stripslashes($row['keyword']));
$description= trim(stripslashes($row['description']));
$logo       = trim($row['logo']);
$copyright  = trim(stripslashes($row['copyright']));

$favicon    = trim($row['favicon']);
$paypal_email   = trim($row['paypal_email']);
```

can anyone tell me what ive missed

much appreciated ty jan x

Comment: `mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS)` what's missing here? I'll make you think about it for a bit. edit: oh and the wrong variable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1):

`$mysqli` is not an object in your code. `$conn` is the object you declared.

Your code should show this:

```
$row        = mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("select * from settings where id = '1' "));
```

Also, you are missing a parameter in the object declaration to set the database itself:

Correct Syntax:

```
$obj = new mysqli("my_host", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Comment: I take it you saw my comment ;-) `mysqli_connect("my_host", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");` wasn't in there initially hehe

Comment: ive put that line in and now im getting the following Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/matureco/public_html/config/db_connect.php on line 7

Comment: heres connection file for db details hun<?php
define ("DBHOST","localhost");
define ("DBUSER","matureco_social");
define ("DBPASS","password");
define ("DBNAME","matureco_social");


/*define ("DBUSER","root");
define ("DBPASS","");
define ("DBNAME","date_demo");*/

define ("DBPREFIX","");
define ("CHAR_SET","utf8");
define ("CACHEDIR","");


?>

Comment: That means that your query is failing, so it's returning a boolean of false instead of a mysqli_result object.

Answer (score 0):

`$mysqli->query("select * from settings where id = '1' "));` should be

```
$conn->query("select * from settings where id = '1' "));
```

since you are going to use oop approach. You should change your code to that way.
this is my suggestion

```
$result       = $conn->query("select * from settings where id = '1' ");
$row = $result->fetch_object()
$site_name  = trim(stripslashes($row->site_name));
$email      = trim($row->email);
$keyword    = trim(stripslashes($row->keyword));
$description= trim(stripslashes($row->description));
$logo       = trim($row->logo);
$copyright  = trim(stripslashes($row->copyright));

$favicon    = trim($row->favicon);
$paypal_email   = trim($row->paypal_email);
```

Comment: ive tried the code above Burak but im just getting further errors

Comment: because i forgot to change thing what i told you to do now i edited it :) i hope it works control your variables syntax email,logo,keyword i might have made mistake while writing them.I am suspicious about trim and stripslashed methods if you get error you had better check these.

Comment: ive resolved that line now im getting a error on line 67 fatal error: call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/matureco/public_html/config/db_connect.php on line 67 `code`if(! function_exists(unReadMsgCount) ) 
{
 function unReadMsgCount($id)
 {
  return $conn->query("select * from messages where rece_id='".$id."' and readflage = 0 and status=1")->num_rows;
 }
}`code`

Comment: it is not easy to solve a code which was written like that.try this after you assigned your conn. if you get error it means your connection is not correct.Check your hostname,id,databasename etc.if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: Ive replaced my connection file with the one in w3c @burak Karasoy and im getting Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user 'matureco_social'@'localhost' to database 'my_db' in /home/matureco/public_html/config/config_global.php on line 3
Failed to connect to MySQLI: Access denied for user 'matureco_social'@'localhost' to database 'my_db'

Comment: Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/matureco/public_html/config/db_connect.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/matureco/public_html/config/db_connect.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/matureco/public_html/config/db_connect.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/matureco/public_html/config/db_connect.php on line 7

Comment: new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,????) where did you assign your database name.

Comment: i since added to here hun $conn  = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME) or die($mysqli->error); but im still getting same errors